# Merge video and audio with ffmpeg. Loop the video while audio is not over

Tags: video, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge an audio file with a video file.

I have two options:

- Have a very small video file (e.g., 10 seconds) that loop while the audio file is not over.
- Have a very long video file (longer than any of my audio file) on which I can attach the audio file. I would like to cut the video when the audio is finished.

I'm using the latter with the `-t <duration in second>` option of ffmpeg. It means I have to get the duration of the audio file to feed it into ffmpeg. Is it possible to avoid this step?

Any pointer for the first solution?

Answer (score 41):

If you want to merge new Audio with video repeat video until the audio finishes, you can try this:

```
ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

Using -stream_loop -1 means infinite loop input.mp4, -shortest means finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends. Here the shortest input stream will be the input.mp3.

And if you want to merge new Audio with video repeat audio until the video finishes, you can try this:

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y out.mp4
```

use -y option will overwrite output files without asking.

Comment: Can you describe how these are different?

Comment: How to do it when the video has no audio?

Comment: This is working perfectly. Was not working previously.  Update the FFMPEG if it is not working for you.

Comment: @minseong, `-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0` already do its job. It will take only video from the first `-i` and only audio from the second `-i` no matter what your second input is video or audio file.

Comment: the first command will execute till the audio finished, imagine having 1-hour audio!

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 He didn't explained but as you can see there's a difference between putting `-stream_loop -1` before or after the determined input i.e. `-i file.mp3` or `-i file.mp4`

Comment: @SatoshiNakamoto Oh, I understand. Thank you. I will try reordering things.

Comment: you need to add `-c copy` or it will re-encode audio and video for no reason

Answer (score 1):

The second bullet point was easily solved by using the -shortest option of ffmpeg. See:  http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC12 for more details.

Comment: This is barely half an answer, it's just a link that only addresses half the question.

Comment: @Zim it was clearly stated in the answer that it addresses only the second bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

For the first bullet point I don't see a direct command. What I'm suggesting is to use `ffprobe` to calculate the duration of both files and calculate the number of video loops that need to play for the duration of audio.

Following will result the duration of the inputs.

```
ffprobe -i input_media -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

Then you can loop the video manually until you satisfy the calculated value of video instances.

```
ffmpeg -i input_audio -f concat -i <(for i in {1..n}; do printf "file '%s'\n" input_video; done) -c:v copy -c:a copy -shortest output_video
```

`1..n` stands for the number of times the video need to be looped. Instead of `-shortest` you can use `-t` as you have already calculated the duration of the audio.

Following is the associated shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
audio_duration=$(ffprobe -i ${1} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
video_duration=$(ffprobe -i ${2} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
n_loops=$(echo "(${audio_duration} / ${video_duration}) + 1"|bc)
ffmpeg -i ${1} -f concat -i <(for i in {1..${n_loops}}; do printf "file '%s'\n" ${2}; done) -c:v copy -c:a copy -shortest ${3}
```

For windows you can convert this shell script to a batch script.

More information:

- [Repeat loop input video with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg)
- [Windows batch scripting](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't think I can use this shell scripting on Windows. Would you have a Windows version?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no pc running on windows. Still you can followup the updated link in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

for the first one, try `ffmpeg -i yourmovie.mp4 -loop 10` to loop the input 10 times

Comment: -loop_input is deprecated, use -loop 1
Note, both loop options only work with -f image2

Comment: can't get -loop 10 nor -loop 1 to work. I'm trying to loop a mp4 video (3 minutes) to audio that is 2 hours long.