# Repeat/loop the video till audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using this command to generate the video from silent video and audio but the problem is video is 3 sec and audio is 20 sec and final video generating is 20 sec but video is for 3 sec and the last frame of that video is repeat till end.

`ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.m4a -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4`

I just want to repeat the whole video

Comment: possibly see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015771/merge-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-loop-the-video-while-audio-is-not-over

Comment: I am looking for the same answer. I'm thinking this might have to be approached with two steps. First make the video only portion then run ffmpeg a second time to loop the video until the audio finishes?