# Merge video and audio with ffmpeg. Loop the video and the audio

Tags: loops, audio, video, ffmpeg

Refering to this: [Merge video and audio with ffmpeg. Loop the video while audio is not over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015771/merge-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-loop-the-video-while-audio-is-not-over)

One answer, well working is:
`ffmpeg  -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y out.mp4`

Thing is that at the end of the music everything stop. Any idea to loop the music too ?
Like an endless video loop over the music, with an endless music loop.

Answer (score 2):

Add another `-stream_loop -1`:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 out.mp4
```

Comment: Simple. Effective ! Thanks