# Why does ffmpeg encoded video freeze on last frame? (VLC playback only)

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, video-encoding

I'm having a situation where I'm combining an audio file with a video where the audio length is longer, using the command below:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i sound.wav output.mp4

Now I don't want to trim the audio to the video length using the -shortest command, however when I playback the output video on VLC (this doesn't happen with other players), the video frame freezes/hangs near the end whilst the audio keeps continuing.

Here's the output video encoding settings (by default):

*cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00*

I would highly appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015771/merge-video-and-audio-with-ffmpeg-loop-the-video-while-audio-is-not-over/55841289#55841289

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.